# API to detect if Android phone has bootloader unlocked?

Tags: android, api, bootloader

Is there any API/code to check if Android phone's bootloader is unlocked?

Comment: This question should be reopened because it is a genuine question asking for an Android API to check whether bootloader is unlocked.

Answer (score 5):

If there was such an API you couldn't trust it because a non-standard ROM could implement it to say whatever it wanted.

Comment: Google's Attestation API now provides this functionality.  The check uses cryptographic keys and must be performed on a server you control; this works around the weakness I noted above.